# Uncaught TypeError: movement is null

Tags: javascript, html, css

Se da el error mencionado en el título del post, se supone que no puede encontrar la etiqueta de html de: #nave, pero está definida sin errores de escritura, no se que puede ser.

```
<!-- HTML -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="javascript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="nave">h</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<!-- CSS -->
*{
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
}
#nave{
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
    margin-top: 790px;
    margin-left: 80px;
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

```
<!-- Javascript -->
var modifier= 5;
var movement = document.getElementById("#nave");
var movedor = document.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
var {style} = movement;
switch (event.key) {
case "ArrowLeft": style.marginLeft = "${parseInt(style.marginLeft) - modifier}px"; break;
case "ArrowRight": style.marginLeft = "${parseInt(style.marginRight) + modifier}px"; break;
    }
  }
);
```

JSADDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD

Comment: ¿Esto que crees que hace?  --> `'var {style} = movement;`   Yo es que no lo entiendo, la verdad, pero quizás si que es algo.

Comment: selecciona los estilos css de la variable movement que a su vez interacciona con el id #nave

Comment: Además de lo que te mencionó Martin en su respuesta: puede que el DOM aún no se haya cargado completamente cuando llamás al script, por lo tanto: o llamás al script _antes de cerrar el `<body>`_, o envolvés tu código en un evento [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event).

Comment: No se, veo errores tipográficos por todas partes... ¿`arrowLeft` no deberia ser `ArrowLeft`?   ¿Y `arrowReft` no deberia ser `ArrowRight`?  ¿Y en javascript las propiedades de los estilos de los elementos no van sin guiones y en camelCase?  Eso me parece haber oido alguna vez en alguna parte. Por cierto, tu error no lo consigo reproducir, a mi no me da nada mal. ¿Quizas falta algo de código en tu pregunta?

Comment: Acabo de corregir los errores de escritura, pero sigue dando el mismo error

Comment: Yo sigo viendo el `"#nave"` en el getElementById cuando deberia ser `"nave"`. Luego veo un `marginRight` que intuyo que esta mal, pues lo asignas al marginLeft, y sigo teniendo mis dudas sobre el `{style}` ese.. ¿de donde sacas esa sintaxis con llaves que dices que selecciona estilos?... Aparte de eso, intentas sumar un string acabado en `px` con un numero y entiendo que primero debes despiezarlo en numero solamente quitandole el `px` porque por mucho que le pongas un `parseInt` seguirá siendo un string a menos que le quites el "px" de algun modo. Y si pones un parseInt con comillas no te irá.

Answer (score 0):

var movement = document.getElementById("nave");
Proba poniendolo asi, porque ya le estas indicando que el elemento a utilizar es un ID asi que creo que no hace falta el #

Comment: No, sigue igual :(

Answer (score 0):

[La página se carga línea por línea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28635195/13419694). El script está antes que el elemento al que intentas acceder. Por lo tanto el body no se cargó completamente y el script no es capaz de encontrar el elemento.

Esto se soluciona poniendo el script al final del body:

```
<body>
    <div id="nave">h</div>
    <script src="javascript.js"></script>
</body>
```

Por otra parte, como te respondió @Martin, al usar [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) solo debes ingresar el ID. Sin **#**.

La alternativa que si lo requiere es [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) y [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) porque usan selectores css para encontrar el elemento.